# Probability: If you roll 6 fair dice, what is the probability that you roll exactly 4 different numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know that the probability will be:

number of outcomes with 4 different numbers/ number of total possible outcomes

Total outcomes: 6^6

I am unsure of how to find the number of outcomes with 4 numbers, my attempt is below:

Outcomes with exactly $4$ numbers being the same: $C(6,4)*C(4, 2)*C(4,2)*C(4,1)*C(3,1)$

I got this from a textbook example, I know that C(6,4) provides the number of combinations (without repetition) of 6 elements into groups of 4, but I am lost beyond that.

Comment: If you want help learning the subject then you will need to give reasons for your answer, so that people can tell you what (if anything) you did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

We count the "favourables." The numbers are small enough that we can break up the calculation into cases.

The collection of $4$ numbers we get can be chosen in $\binom{6}{4}$ ways. Now we count the number of ways our sequence of tosses can be made up of say $1,2,3,4$.

The $6$ tosses can yield the numbers $1,2,3,4$ is the following ways:

(i) One number occurs $3$ times, and the others once each. I would call this Type $3$-$1$-$1$-$1$. The popular number can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways. Its location can be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways. And then the rest of the positions can be filled  in $3!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{3}3!$.

(ii) Two numbers occur twice each, and the other two once each. We can call this Type $2$-$2$-$1$-$1$.  The popular numbers can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. For each such way, the locations of the smaller popular number can be chosen in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, and then the locations of the other popular number can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. The remaining positions can then be filled in $2!$ ways, for a total of $\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}2!$.

For the number of favourables, add up (i) and (ii), and multiply by $\binom{6}{4}$. For the probability, divide by $6^6$.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of getting exactly $k$ different values when you throw $n$ fair $r$-sided dice is $${{r\choose k}{n\brace k}k!\over r^n},$$ where $n\brace k$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). With $n=6$, $r=6$, and $k=4$ this gives $325/648\approx .50154.$

Comment: have not used stirling numbers yet, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

For small problems, you could uniformly formulate favorable ways as

$3-1-1-1-0-0 : \binom{6}{3,1,1,1,0,0}\cdot\frac{6!}{3!2!}= 7200$

$2-2-1-1-0-0 : \binom{6}{2,2,1,1,0,0}\cdot\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}= 16,200$

$Pr = \dfrac{23,400}{6^6} = \dfrac{325}{648}$

**PS:**

The formula can also be  written as the product of two multinomial coefficients, representing choose  and place, e.g., as $\binom{6}{3,2,1}\binom{6}{3,1,1,1,0,0}$